# Best format to send LoRa data (JSON, RAW?? ) and what about security

Tags: esp32, lora

What's the best format (most efficient) way to transit GPS and ID data via LoRa radio signal , using an arduino ESP32 . I have setup a radio and built JSON strings but for such a low bandwidth format I suspect there's a better more efficient way.

Also what's the best way to handle security, just base64 and encrypt your own data or is there a standardized format?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Cayenne Low Power Payload (LPP). Cayenne specifies a GPS Location data type.

https://mydevices.com/cayenne/docs/lora/#lora-cayenne-low-power-payload
https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/devices/arduino/api/cayennelpp.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You could choose whatever format fits your scenario as long as you keep the payloads small.
2. The payload and the LoraWan packet are both encrypted. So you don't have to worry about doing your own encryption.

Comment: Ok I'm using JSON and and am trying to keep it under 255bytes (1 LorA Packet) , but Im experiencing bad JSON even for short ranges.

Comment: what do you mean bad JSON? could you put some examples in your question?

Comment: @user265505 you should use something like Cayenne LPP not JSON to send data over LoRA.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow my thoughts below:

> What's the best format (most efficient) way to transit GPS and ID data
>   via LoRa radio signal , using an arduino ESP32 . I have setup a radio
>   and built JSON strings but for such a low bandwidth format I suspect
>   there's a better more efficient way.

LoRa and LoRaWAN are designed for low-power wide area networks, you may set a self-defined data format to keep your payload as short as possible.

> Also what's the best way to handle security, just base64 and encrypt
>   your own data or is there a standardized format?

LoRa and LoRaWAN are not same. LoRa is the PHY layer of LoRaWAN. As you mentioned, you are using LoRa. You may find an encryption approach that would not increase the payload length too much to find a balance point between energy consumption and security. There is no standard payload format.

Additional comment: I have to say that LoRa is not a good choice if security is a critical issue in your App.